# Change of variables with a continuous but not differentiable mapping

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, piecewise-linear

Suppose that Y is a continuous random variable with a density function $f_{Y}(y)$. We transform $Y$ by the following mapping

\begin{equation} Y^{*} =  \left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
\alpha Y + \beta &  \text{ if } Y < y^{0} \\
 Y &  \text{ if } Y > y^{0}
\end{array} \right .
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known constants such that the mapping is continuous, but not differentiable at $Y = y^{0}$. How do I find the density function of $Y^{*}$?

My concern is how the non-differentiable point $Y=y^0$ affects the resulting density of $Y^∗$. My solution for the density of $Y^∗$ is the following:

$f_{Y^{*}}(y^{*}) = f_{Y}(y^{*}) I\{ Y^{*} > y^{0} \} +  \frac{1}{\alpha}f_{Y}\left (  \frac{y^{*} - \beta}{\alpha} \right) I\{ Y^{*} < \alpha y^{0} + \beta  \}. $

Comment: Is this a problem for a course? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It's no a problem for a course.

Comment: My concern is how the non-differentiable point $Y = y^{0}$ affects the resulted density of $Y^{*}$. My solution for the density of $Y^{*}$ is 1. for $ Y  > y^{0}$ (equivalently, $Y^{*} > y^{0}$), $f_{Y^{*}}(y^{*}) = f_{Y}(y)$; 2. for  $Y  < y^{0}$, $f_{Y^{*}}(y^{*}) = f_{Y}(y)/\alpha$.

Comment: I tried to add this information into your question. Please ensure it says what you want it to.

Comment: A complete and thorough answer to the *general* question posed here might be difficult to formulate, but in this particular case ask yourself what the probability assigned to the nondifferentiable points is.  If that probability is zero, does the lack of differentiability make any difference?

Comment: I think if that probability is zero, the lack of differentiability makes no difference.  That implies I dont need to worry about my concern.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603426/conditions-for-this-functional-relating-densities-under-change-of-variables-to-e

Answer (score 1):

The transform leads to a cumulative distribution function that is non-differentiable in the point where you split the transformation.

The density function will have a [jump discontinuity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) in that point. Possibly there are ways to still have the density defined in a way (e.g. use the [directional continuity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Directional_and_semi-continuity) of the cumulative distribution function or an average as you did) but the discontinuity remains.

Below you see an example when we perform such transformation on the normal distribution

[image: example with normal distribution]